# Installing Pyinstaller on Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller, python-3.7

I have been trying to install Pyinstaller on a Mac computer. I am having trouble getting the terminal to execute the `setup.py` file needed to install it. Whenever I type `python setup.py install` in the terminal, I receive this error:

`python: cant open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

I have tried moving the pyinstaller folder to the same folder as my python application and changing the directory that the terminal is acting in using "cd Downloads" or other directories and nothing has worked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried running that command while in `Downloads/pyinstaller`?

Comment: You need to `cd` into the directory where `setup.py` is located.

Answer (score 0):

Using a more specific cd command such as "cd Downloads/pyinstaller" instead of "cd Downloads" works.